# How to query sets and subsets and get a set that doesn't contain the other set

Tags: sql, set

I think i have a somewhat simple problem but due to my lack of experience in DB modelling and SQL i'm unable to get the right solution, 
i can draw the basic concept but i'm having a hard time to implement a solution

Let's say i have some sets A,B and C.

A is inside B

B is inside C

A is the set of the 10 objects with greatest value inside B set

B is the set of all values greater than 100

C is the set of all values greater than 50

[image]

that's the easy part,

Now i need to get 50 objects with the greatst value from C that are not inside A 
How would i translate that problem to the SQL language, or what commands, tools or design patterns should i use to solve this problem?

I'm not sure if I was clear enough,
again sorry if the problem is too trivial for some, but i'm trying to learn more about SQL and designs.

I'm looking for a general solution that it's not bound by a framework or OS

Thanks for any help

Comment: you want to look up window functions (sometimes called analytic functions), specifically `row_number() over (order by)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply,but how would enumerating rows would help me?

Comment: what db engine You want to use?

Comment: sql and data modelling are related, but different.  To learn more about each, I've heard good things about the books, Database Design for Mere Mortals and Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  The key thing about sql, is that the s stands for Structured, not Standard.  That means that a query that runs successfully in  database engine A might crash in database engine B.

Comment: `i need to get 50 objects with the greatst value from C that are not inside A` => could they be inside B too or only C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a table `t` with a `value` column, and that the labels "A", "B", and "C" are based on these.

```
select t.*
from t left outer join
     (select value
      from t
      where value >= 100
      order by value desc
      limit 1
     ) A
     on t.value = A.value
where t.value >= 50 and A.value is null
order by value desc
limit 50;
```

The use of `limit` is database specific.  It might be `top` or `rownum` in the `where` clause or something else depending on the database.

EDIT:

If the sets are large enough, you could just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where value >= 50 and value < 100
order by value desc
limit 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this query would help:

```
select Col1,Max(Col2) from
(select col1, col2 from TableC
Except
Select col1, col2 from TableA)as A
Group By Col1
```

Here the inner query would only select the records which are there in table A but not in Table C, and then outer query would take the max of those records.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. if I consider A, B and C your SQL tables and assume that they have some sort of relation between them then you can write your query something like

SELECT C.* FROM C WHERE C.ID NOT IN

(SELECT B.ID FROM B JOIN A ON B.ID = A.ID)

The subquery (Second line) gives you all the objects which are common between B and A (so essentially A).

Again I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, it would be helpful if you can share your real life scenario here.

For set theory and SQL understanding please refer to below article

http://seanmehan.globat.com/blog/2011/12/20/set-theory-and-sql-concepts/